# Does an RTD simulator require calibration?

Tags: simulation, calibration, rtd

Does an RTD simulator need calibration or not? Basically, I can measure that the value of RTD with a calibrated multimeter and I can show the difference between multimeter and RTD simulator. So, can you explain to me if an RTD simulator needs calibration or can I calibrate it with a calibrated multimeter?

Comment: https://www.fluke.com/en-ca/learn/blog/calibration/rtd-and-thermocouple-simulationfor-calibration-and-testing Can you understand this? or this https://us.flukecal.com/literature/articles-and-education/temperature-calibration/application-notes/how-calibrate-rtd-or-pla

Answer (score 1):

RTDs have known predictable performance, and yes, you can confirm the performance of your simulator up to the precision limit of your multimeter using a calibrated multimeter.

Whether or not you can call adjustments you make calibration depends on who the audience is and if you have the right paperwork.